# JavaScript - Why isn't this working? I can't see the difference

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting out here but I've got these two sections of JS code. The first block is an example from a book that I copied and pasted, the second block is one that I typed out and is (in my eyes) identical to the first block. However when I run the code, the second block (the one I typed) just doesn't work. I've looked at each character and can't find out why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Chapter 2, Question 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var firstNumber = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the first number",""));
            var secondNumber = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the second number",""));
            var theTotal = firstNumber + secondNumber;

            document.write(first number + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals " + theTotal);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "just doesn't work" is not a proper problem explanation.

Comment: `first number` != `firstNumber`

Comment: For future reference, you should really consult your console (hit F12). It would have told you that you have a syntax error.

Comment: Just to clarify, the error is in the first one but you say that works and the second one doesn't?  We know that's not right so did you just get the explanation wrong?

Comment: @MikeC Thanks for that. How would I use the console to find out what's wrong? I've got it open but it doesn't show me much apart from showing me a log of what I've done

Comment: @Archer I think I got them the wrong way round :S My first post on here isn't going well. Sorry guys

Comment: @ShadowCoder The console is useful for all kinds of things. For example, [it would have shown you a syntax error](https://jsfiddle.net/skxxvh6j/) and on what line. Then you can look closely at that line to see what's wrong. [You can also log your own stuff to it](https://jsfiddle.net/41mmkaaq/) which is super helpful when you want to know what's going on in your code.

Comment: Lol. Thanks for clarifying. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't anything else.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks for the help man

Comment: @Archer Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space in first number.

This:

```
document.write(first number + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals " + theTotal);
```

should be:

```
document.write(firstNumber + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals " + theTotal);
```

Comment: Good eye. Read it three times and missed it each time.

Comment: Ah damn! Thanks! A fresh look on things is pretty helpful at times :)

Comment: @ShadowCoder what is helpful is checking console for errors, not a "fresh look"

Comment: Yes it can be hard to spot some times. Especially when it looks somewhat grammatically correct. As others are mentioning it is always a good idea to keep the console open to spot any errors like this.

Comment: @zerkms How can I use the console to 'debug' such an issue? Serious question

Comment: F12 in your browser will show a console log, which would have displayed an error for 'first number' not defined or something.

Comment: @xCRKxTyPHooN What if I'm on a Mac?

Comment: Oh, not sure never developed on a mac.  But here this should help https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html